# How to get google advertising id in my app while designing android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-advertising-id

I need to retrieve google advertising id to be use in an SDK in my android app in android studio. How do I do that?.

```
TheoremReach.initWithApiKeyAndUserIdAndActivityContext("40xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "ANDROID_TEST_ID", this);
```

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve Admob id?
Your question is unclear!

Comment: No, the SDK am using us asking for Google Advertising Id, I don't even know what that is.

Comment: In place of Android Test Id, I need to enter Google Advertising Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your Advertising ID in Google account setting. Follow the below navigation in an Android phone to get the ID.

Settings > Google (also named as Google Settings) > Ads > Your advertising ID (This is where you will get the ID)